# Creating a Query Interface in C?

Tags: c, user-interface, interface

This is my first time programming in the C language, and I'm stuck trying to create a query interface.

What I mean by this, is say I have some data and I have a function CreateGraph().

I want CreateGraph to be able to take these queries

CreateGraph < header > < bars > < start date/time> < end date/time>

where these queries are entered by the user in runtime on the console.
Example: CreateGraph MyGraph 7 blue 10
would produce a blue graph with 7 bars of size 10 with the title myGraph.

Very confused on how to accomplish this. Thanks. (This is based off of an assignment I am trying to accomplish, but I just want the general idea)

Comment: Maybe you could post specific examples of code you are confused by and the things you tried to attempting a more perfect understanding?

Comment: It's not necessarily the code I'm confused about, it's more or less the structure and where to begin. I tried finding anything about "query interface" but nothing.

Comment: In C, I always find #include <stdio.h> a good opening line.

Comment: Alright, I'll try some stuff and update.

Comment: Well, I simplified the question just to understand the concept. All I want to be able to do is, once in runtime, I want to be able to type "MultiplyByTen 20" into the console and have it print out 200. I have a function MultiplyByTen(int x). Do I use stdin, store it into a char array, if the first word matches my function name, call the function and use the following token as my int x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is use command line arguments as flags for the execution of a program. In C, you wouldn't call the function specifically from the command line, since there's no way of doing that (at least to my knowledge). What you would do, however, is use *argc* and *argv*.

When writing a main function in C, you'll often just write

```
int main (){
   //code
}
```

but that's not the only way of doing it. You can also write

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   //code
}
```

These argc and argv are variables that hold the data given to the program in the command line. A basic run would just look like

```
>./a.out
```

In this case, './a.out' is actually a command line argument, starting the program run. So if you type in

```
>./a.out MyGraph 7 blue 10
```

argc would be an `int` with value 5, and argv an array containing each string in the line, delimited by spaces

```
["./a.out","MyGraph", "7", "blue", "10"]
```

These can then be accessed like any other array of char*'s in C.

This being said, the case you have in your question lends itself better to either reading input from a file or during runtime from the user using scanf.

Edit: Now that I reread your question, scanf seems like a much better option. In C, to get user input during the execution of a program, you can use the function `scanf`. I'd suggest doing a google search on how to get user input in C, since it's more complicated than I'd like to write in this answer. AFAIK, "Query interfaces" aren't a thing in C

Comment: Yes, this question is part of a larger project. I'm already taking in a file from a command line argument in argv[] which is where I am pulling all of my data. My assignment is unfortunately asking for the user to type the function name followed by the parameters into the console. I believe I can check if the first word is a function name using stdin, call that function, then use the following tokens entered as the parameters for that function.

Comment: Use `scanf` for that. You can write prompts to the console using `printf` and use `scanf` to get user input. Look them up online and watch a few tutorials on them, they're relatively simple